# Remove a div with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to remove this div

```
<div id="myid" class="myclass">other_tags_here</div>
```

I am using

```
preg_replace ("/<div id=\"myid\" class=\"myclass\">/", "", $buffer)
```

but this removes only the first opening tag while I want to remove both opening and closing tags as well as all tags in between.

Thank you

Comment: This is awfully hard to achieve with `preg_replace()`...

Comment: Processing html with regexes will just make [Tony the Pony](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/118068) trot up to your front door and knock out your teeth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do this. Please use the very nice [**PHP DOM facilities**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Although a regex can be written to match your particular case, this will be **[fragile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)**.

Comment: Can you please give me a hint where exactly I should look in PHP DOM facilities? Thanx

Comment: @yann http://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.installation.php . It should already be there :)

Answer (score 1):

in order to remove everything in between elements you should do somthing like this

```
    preg_replace ("/<div id=\"myid\" class=\"myclass\">.*?<\/div>/", "", $buffer);
```

Comment: And what happens when anohter div is inside? Your pc explodes!